# How to print a special character in python

Tags: python

For my python program, I want to print the special character ℝ in the console. I'm searching for a simple way to do so.

My code is:

```
a = int(input("a? "))
while a == 0 :
    a = int(input("a? "))
b = int(input("b? "))
c = int(input("c? "))

D = pow(b,2) - 4*a*c
if D>0:
    x1 = -b - pow(D,0.5)
    x1 = x1 / 2*a
    x2 = -b + pow(D,0.5)
    x2 = x2 / 2*a
    print("x1 = " + str(x1))
    print("x2 = "+ str(x2))
elif D==0:
    x0 = -b / 2*a
    print("x0 = " + str(x0))
else:
    print("Cette équation n'a pas de racines dans R")
input()
```

Comment: I just checked your solution. It didn't work... It still displays a Traceback error.

Comment: you using python3 or python2?

Comment: Guys, none of the suggested solutions worked. It still prints the same error.

Comment: if you are getting an error, posting that error can go along way to figuring out your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First look up the unicode character http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/211d/index.htm
Then you can either place the unicode character itself directly in the source:

Python2:

```
print(u"ℝ")
```

Python3:

```
print("ℝ")
```

Or use the escape code:

```
print("\u211D")
```

Or you can store it as bytes and decode it:

```
bytes("\xE2\x84\x9D").decode('utf-8')
```

Answer (score 3):

You are going to want to print the unicode code.

`print(u"\u211D")`